# Auto completar ao digitar qualquer parte da palavra

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, autocompletar, listbox, planilha

Como posso **autocompletar** o texto ao digitar qualquer parte de uma informação dentro da ListBox usando VBA?

Exemplo:

Ao digitar a *"Santos"* todas as opções que contenham essa palavra serão listadas / apresentadas na listbox.

Comment: não percebi muito bem a sua questão mas, veja neste URL: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db

Talvez ajude.

Comment: Na verdade criei uma listbox para alimentar uma célula, e queria que ao digitar uma palavra ou parte dela a listbox apresentasse todos os itens que contenham parte daquela palavra digitada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola,

primeiro preencha a lista 
depois percorra os itens e crie a lista filtrada

```
Dim i As Integer
'Percorre por todos itens do listbox
For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
'Verifica se o item do listbox esta selecionado
if InStr(List1.List(i),valorDigitado) = 0 then
ListFiltrada.add(List1.List(i))
End If
Next
```

algo assim, estou sem windows para criar o codigo preciso